# Is there a normal separable sequential $\aleph$-space with uncountable extent?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

It is a classical fact from the undergraduate course of General Topology that under CH (more precisely, under $2^{\omega_1}>\mathfrak c$) every separable normal space has countable extent, i.e., does not contain uncountable closed discrete subspaces.

On the other hand, MA$+\neg $CH there are examples which are separable, normal, and have uncountable extent. One of such examples is the Mrowka-Isbell space $\Psi(\mathcal A)$ for a suitable uncountable almost disjoint family $\mathcal A$. The Mrowka-Isbell space is even a $\sigma$-space, i.e., has a $\sigma$-discrete network.

I am interested in finding such counterexamples among sequential $\aleph$-spaces.

Let us recall that a *regular* topological space $X$ is an *$\aleph$-space* if it has a $\sigma$-discrete $k$-network.

A family $\mathcal N$ of subsets of a topological space $X$ is called a *$k$-network* if for any open set $U\subset X$ and any compact subset $K\subset U$ there exists a finite subfamily $\mathcal F\subset\mathcal N$ such that $K\subset\bigcup\mathcal F\subset U$.

> **Problem.** Is there an example of a normal separable sequential $\aleph$-space with uncountable extent?

**Remark.** Such space, if exists, should have uncountable sequential order. In this case also $2^{\omega_1}=\mathfrak c$.

Comment: The classical fact is known as [Jones' lemma](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/jones-lemma/) as you probably know.